# Lightbox in php to show information in pop-up

Tags: php, javascript, popup, lightbox

I'm Developing an application, that have several Pages for the application. And In it i thought to Say one information in it, it the user like to proceed means they can continue or can drop that..

Now i have query like,..

```
<input type="Button" onclick="window.open(myPage.php)" target="_blank" value="Guess It..!"/>
```

It opens a new page for showing the Data,.. Its looking good. But just now i came to knew about the Lightbox functionality in PHP with javascript. I Heard that it will perform my process in the Same page without disturbing the Previous one, it came as pop-up and after completing its Process we can close and continue our previous process..

I Hope i will help to my user to work easily without any confusion with the New Tab Open option, now i'm searching for the lightbox Tutorial, anybody suggest me for the Best tutorial or examples..

Comment: For those, u just go for javascript and jquery popup lightbox plugin. I think it will be worthy and easy..
[Popup](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/343/JavaScript-Popup-lightbox)

Answer (score 2):

I think you shuuld look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). Good documentation, easy to use, you can dynamic load content, images etc.

There is also [tutorial](http://fancybox.net/howto) and [documentation](http://fancybox.net/api).

Answer (score 2):

http://fancybox.net/

Download and use this fancy box..This will be easy for you to implement and customize based on reqs.

For using it, refer http://fancybox.net/howto.

Hope it helps.